# How to create a RegExp to match 3 unique chars and 2 optional chars at the end?

Tags: python, regex

Hey would anyone be able to help me create a regex for Python that has a minimum of 3 characters and a max of 5 characters? the first 3 characters have to be unique and the last two optional characters can be any characters.

Once again, the last two characters can be anything! (even the same as one of the first 3 characters)

This is what I have right now: `^(?:(\w)(?!.*\1)){3}\w{0,2}$`

The only problem with this regex is that it does not allow the last two characters to be the same as any of the first 3. (eg. pfaab doesnt work when it should)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're pretty close.  Your negative lookahead needs to limit how far ahead it looks.  And there's no need to test the third character of the first three.  See my answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should work:

```
^(\w)(?!.?\1)(\w)(?!\2)\w{1,3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dL6zG1)

Comment: +1 for using regex101.com. Haven't seen that one before.